# Проигрывание трека в аудиоплеере при смене страницы сайта во вкладке браузера

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, rest

Не так давно делаю сайт для музыки на Wordpress. На данный момент осуществил возможность добавления и получения данных из БД. Опишу, как работает страница со списком альбомов:

1. Для создания ссылок на альбомы из БД загружаются значения Исполнитель, Название альбома, Изображение (ссылка на изображение для альбома), Жанр. Рендеринг производится сервером, итоговая разметка отдаётся клиенту.
2. При переходе по ссылке на альбом отправляется GET-запрос к серверу по адресу, где находится путь для вывода данных в JSON через REST API. Через функцию на сервере производится возвращение строк из БД, в которых присутствуют одновременно Исполнитель и Альбом. Данные отдаются в виде JSON-массива на этой же странице GET-запроса.
3. Ответ (массив JSON-объектов), преобразуется в JS-объект на стороне клиента. Далее берутся значения Трек (название трека), Название аудиофайла, для данного исполнителя, и с ними создаются html-ссылки с параметром onclick, равному вызову процедуры с GET-запросом. При проходе по такой ссылке отправляется GET-запрос к серверу, а на последнем снова осуществляется поиск в БД, и возвращается ссылка на данный трек в виде массива JSON-объектов в путь, по которому был осуществлён запрос. Полученный JSON-объект, как это делалось ранее, но в случае с получением списка треков альбома, конвертируется в JS-объект. Далее из объекта берётся ссылка на файл и присваивается переменной, а последняя подставляется в процедуру (JS на стороне клиента), где файл, находящийся по данной ссылке, воспроизводится.
4. Теперь по полученным ссылкам можно осуществить проигрывание треков.  Однако в случае загрузки любой другой страницы сайта в этой же вкладке музыка играть перестанет.

Как можно осуществить непрерывное проигрывание музыки на сайте? Я сталкивался с ответами вроде "необходимо создать SPA", однако некоторые говорят, что такой необходимости нет. Например, я слышал про такие вещи, как передача данных с одной страницы на другую в JS. Только вот не представляю, можно ли это использовать в данном случае.